# How Itachi was able to use Shadow clone?

Tags: naruto

In Episode 452 of Naruto Shippuden,

Itachi used his shadow clone which was in Academy and he was himself training in forest. Since he is already very young then how come he was able to use Shadow clone. According to the teacher of Academy he was so talented that they graduated him but still how we was able to use it.

According to Fugaku Uchiha (His father), he has never used Shadow clone and also as per wiki Jutsu section its only states that he used only Fire release Jutsu.

Since his Father was the only one who teach him various Jutsu then how he learned Shadow Clone? Is it his Father who teach him or Itachi alone was able to learn by himself?

Comment: sharingan . . . 
copying other shinobi . . .

Comment: You really think Itachi used sharigan when he was so young?

Comment: Episode 452 is a filler, not canon. It was not from the manga.

Comment: prodigy, genius or whatever

Comment: @AyaseEri I am asking about Anime only that's why I stated episode no and to be very true I really don't know the ending of this series so I am following only Anime not manga. Even though its a filler but still I guess its a real story of his childhood.

Comment: @AyaseEri Itachi has used Shadow Clone jutsu in chapter 142. While episode 452 may not be canon, his use of the jutsu definitely is.

Comment: Itachi Uchiha was a mysterious man. You'll never know what he can do unless he does it.

Answer (score 1):

It was never confimed in the cannon of Naruto-verse. However it can be inferred that such a technique can be self taught.

*Naruto did it.*

With a shinobi as good as Itachi, who mastered the art of Sharingan at the age of 8, and having joining Anbu at the age of 11 [Itachi wiki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Itachi_Uchiha), it shouldn't be hard to self-teach the **B-ranked** Shadow-clone jutsu.

Shadow clone Jutsu not imposing any blood-line limits (kekkei genkei)- and  Itachi being a prodigy above all others-  he could have copied the jutsu with his activated sharingan.

Comment: Itachi has used the Shadow Clone jutsu in canon (manga chapter 142). Also, in the episode 452, Itachi is shown using the jutsu at the age of 6 before he activated the Sharingan.

Comment: @MaskedMan By Cannon i inferred towards the context of itachi learning the shadow clone Jutsu. We have no canon material on that.

Comment: Episode 452 is basically Filler, though it might be based on other works about Itachi by the Author making it Canon, in terms of the manga only, it is pure filler, and we all know how dangerous it is to walk on a path of Filler with all them Plot holes. Itachi does Canonically know Shadow clone justu, but when and how he learned it (just like all jutsu learned by everyone but naruto) is ambiguous.

Comment: @SeasonalShot You know that Itachi used to ask from his father to teach him Jutsu and he used to go out and use Fireball Jutsu. Since Fireball Jutsu is C -rank jutsu so for that he need guidance for his father. But in case of Shadow clone jutsu it is B - Rank jutsu which means it is much harder to learn than fireball jutsu. So I don't think that it is self taught. Because if it is self taught then he would have learned fireball jutsu by himself and he would have never said "Teach me Jutsu Father".

Comment: @Ryan Exactly my view. It's non-canon, any argument will end up in ambiguity.

Comment: @LightYagami Yes, you are correct, Fireball Jutsu is C rank whilst Shadow clone jutsu is B. But then again, we are talking about Uchiha Itachi -the legendary shinobi. Be that as it may, if Naruto can learn it by himself, i don't see why Itachi couldn't too. Plus, Plus he consistently asked his father to teach new jutsu coz he's already so much ahead of what's being taught at the school.

Comment: Naruto didn't self teach the Shadow Clone Jutsu. He "aquired" the hidden scroll for Multiple Shadow Clone, and considering that it is just a scaled up version, he also learned the "normal" version.